# Use percentile of one column to be used by another column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, percentile

I need to rank a column by the percentile of another column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.percent_rank

val df = List((13,3), (12,5), (11,7), (8,8), (4,5), (3,4), (2,1), (1,2), (1,6) ,(1,12)).toDF("val1","val2")

val w =  Window.orderBy(df("val1"))
df.select($"val1", $"val2",percent_rank().over(w).alias("val1_percent")).show()
```

The result I get is:

```
+----+----+------------------+
|val1|val2|      val1_percent|
+----+----+------------------+
|   1|   2|               0.0|
|   1|   6|               0.0|
|   1|  12|               0.0|
|   2|   1|0.3333333333333333|
|   3|   4|0.4444444444444444|
|   4|   5|0.5555555555555556|
|   8|   8|0.6666666666666666|
|  11|   7|0.7777777777777778|
|  12|   5|0.8888888888888888|
|  13|   3|               1.0|
+----+----+------------------+
```

But I want to get is the rank of the column "val2" with the percentile of "val1", i.e in the table below I want to get the column "val2_percent":

```
+----+----+------------------+----------------+
|val1|val2|      val1_percent|val2_percent    |
+----+----+------------------+----------------+
|   1|   2|               0.0|0.333           |
|   1|   6|               0.0|0.611           |
|   1|  12|               0.0|0.888           |
|   2|   1|0.3333333333333333|0               |
|   3|   4|0.4444444444444444|0.555           |
|   4|   5|0.5555555555555556|0.583           |
|   8|   8|0.6666666666666666|0.666           |
|  11|   7|0.7777777777777778|0.638           |
|  12|   5|0.8888888888888888|0.583           |
|  13|   3|               1.0|0.444           |
+----+----+------------------+----------------+
```

Please note that in Excel it works well with the method PERCENTRANK. You can use it like that: PERCENTRANK([val1 all values],[one value of val2])

EDIT:
In Excel I put all the values of val1 in column A, and all the values of val2 in column B. For the following formula =PERCENTRANK(A1:A10,B1) I get 0.333 (if B1 = 2)

Comment: How is `val2_percent` calculated? It's not clear to me.

Comment: in Excel you write like that: I put all the val1 in column A, and if I write`=PERCENTRANK(A1:A10,3)` I get 0.333

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your question. Without excel, how do you compute val2_percent

Comment: @eliasah https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PERCENTRANK-function-f1b5836c-9619-4847-9fc9-080ec9024442

Comment: @JacekLaskowski LOL I know how to use excel but I'm not sure what is the range A1:A10 represent :)

Comment: In Excel I wrote like that: I put all the val1 in column A, and all the values of val2 in column B. For the following formula `=PERCENTRANK(A1:A10,B1)` I get 0.333 (if B1 = 3)

Comment: Oh ok... How many values do you have in val2 ? Because this is just some crazy expensive computation you are trying to perform there !

Comment: Maybe it is expensive, but this what I need to do. Lets say that Val2 has 5 values

Comment: than you divide your DF into 5 iterating over each value from val2 and compute grouped ntile than union of the array of DF